# Complex Group by with lambda

Tags: c#, performance, datatable, group-by, grouping

I would like to group my datatable using C# LINQ query and return table with lowest and highest price. For example the bellow table will be grouped by ItemNumber and next by Cat1. For the produced result I need to get lowest and highest price of the Group.

```
ItemNumber  Cat1    Low Price   High Price
100         Item1   1           10
150         Item2   2           11
100         Item1   2           12
150         Item2   5           18
```

Result

```
ItemNumber  Cat1    Low Price   High Price
100         Item1   1           12
150         Item2   2           18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the result is another `DataTable` with the aggregated data:

```
var aggrTable = table.Clone(); // schema only
var groups = table.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => new { ItemNumber = r.Field<int>("ItemNumber"), Cat1 = r.Field<string>("Cat1") });
foreach(var group in groups)
{
    DataRow row = aggrTable.Rows.Add();
    row.SetField("ItemNumber", group.Key.ItemNumber);
    row.SetField("Cat1", group.Key.Cat1);
    row.SetField("Low Price", group.Min(r => r.Field<int>("Low Price")));
    row.SetField("High Price", group.Max(r => r.Field<int>("High Price")));
}
```

Result-table (tested with your sample data):

```
    ItemNumber    Cat1       Low Price   High Price
      100         Item1         1           12
      150         Item2         2           18
```